# SQL Developer says incompatible version

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL Developer version is 4.0.3, database 11.2.0.

Full message appears when I try to connect to my database:

"incompatible version of libocijdbc 112030, jdboci 112020

The laptop on which this occurs has Java 7 Update 51 and java SE Dev kit 7upd51 installed.

I tried a reinstall of SQL Developer but no change.

has anyone any idea of how to solve this problem ???

Comment: SQL Developer ver. 4? Why *that old*? Why wouldn't you download the newest version? It successfully connects to a 11g database (I know, I have it).

Comment: Was not successful in creating an account with Oracle to get the latest version. Tried but got nowhere.